# Не отображается карта на androide. Вместо нее черный экран с кнопками управления

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Здравствуйте, такая проблема.

На планшете, не отображается `Google Maps V2` в приложении. Вместо карты черный экран, но есть кнопки управления (`ZoomIn, ZoomOut`). В консоле никаких ошибок не наблюдается. `API` ключ верный. На планшете стоит android 4.0.4  но вроде не его родной, как сказали, его перепрошили до такой версии.

`android-support-v4.jar` и `google-play-services` к проекту подключены.

На телефоне с `android 4.1.2` приложение работает нормально и карта отображается.

В чем может быть проблема и в какую сторону копать ?

Гугловское приложение Карты на планшете работает вроде нормально.

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте скомпилировать под SKD API 15

Comment: Знаю что не рекомендованное поведение.
Но я не с плохими намерениями это делаю :)
Приложение не публичное, и используется в фирме и на устройствах фирмы.

Comment: Как поменять статус вопроса на решен ?

Comment: Закрывайте мой ответ (галочка слева)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блокировка кнопки HOME не есть хорошо. Блокировка кнопки HOME - это нерекомендованное поведение - после ICS это уже запрещено

Чтобы заблокировать HOME перепрошивайте на кастомную прошивку где блокировка HOME разрешено. Некоторые так и делают. Или как вариант - ставьте только <=ICS